# OSM Line 'way' from PostgreSQL (PostGIS) to Java Linestring (from JTS library)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, java, jts-topology-suite

I would like to read the data from PostGIS OSM database to Java object. I have 'planet_osm_line' table. I'd like to get 'osm_id' and 'way' column read by ResultSet, as here:

```
stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
List<OSMLineData> osmLineDataList = new ArrayList<OSMLineData>();
while (rs.next()) {
    LineString ls = (LineString) rs.getObject("way");
    OSMLineData osmLineData = new OSMLineData(rs.getInt("osm_id"), (LineString) rs.getObject("way"));
    osmLineDataList.add(osmLineData);
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
return osmLineDataList;
```

However, I get an ereor:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString
```

When I change it to read String `rs.getString(way)`, and I also change the class variable type from Linestring to String, I am getting some weird representation of 'way' data.

I thought that it would be ok to import data for 'way' column with 'st_astext(way)' to the variable of String type, and then somehow change it to Linestring type from JTS. Is this a correct way? Is there a different, more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (that I know of) is to use the [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) library to handle all the complex database interaction and geometry conversions. Your code boils down to this:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.key, PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.sample);
params.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.PORT.key, 5432);
params.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.HOST.key, "localhost");
params.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.HOST.key, "localhost");
params.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.USER.key, "ian");
params.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.PASSWD.key, "ianian");
params.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.DATABASE.key, "osm");
params.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.SCHEMA.key, "ospr");
DataStore postgisDS = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
SimpleFeatureSource source = postgisDS.getFeatureSource("ways");
List<OSMLineData> osmLineDataList = new ArrayList<>();
try (SimpleFeatureIterator it = source.getFeatures().features()) {
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    SimpleFeature feature = it.next();
    OSMLineData osmLineData = new OSMLineData(feature.getID(), (LineString) feature.getDefaultGeometry());
    osmLineDataList.add(osmLineData);
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

On the PostGIS side, use [`ST_AsBinary(way)`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_AsBinary.html) to convert your geometry to [well-known binary (WKB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary) format.

On the Java side, read the WKB into a `byte[]` with the [`getBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBytes(int)) method of `ResultSet` and use a JTS [`WKBReader`](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/index.html) to parse the `byte[]` array into a JTS geometry.

You can also use [`ST_AsText`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html), but your geometries will be modified slightly because `ST_AsText` does not preserve full coordinate precision.